# Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class for Paho/Mqtt

Tags: android, gradle, paho

Hi I am currently working on an android project using android studio. I would like to use the Paho/Mqtt library but I seem to encounter a problem when building.
These are the relevant elements in the **build.gradle** file

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.1'
    compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

There is 56 errors, but the build still shows as BUILD SUCCESSFUL.

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

and this same message shows up 5 more times for

```
(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$1
(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketSecureNetworkModule$1)
(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketNetworkModule$1)
(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence$1)
(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence$2)
```

This is the logs in the Gradle Console

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient$2) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketSecureNetworkModule$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketNetworkModule$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence$2) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
```

I tried fixing this error by adding in my **proguard-rules.pro** file

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-dontoptimize
```

As well as these lines in the *defaultConfig* block of the **build.gradle** file

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

The two above solutions still left me with the same 56 errors. Would anyone know what to do in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be an optimal answer but the I changed the version to **1.1.2-SNAPSHOT** and the build was actually successful. I'll see if I encounter any other error. let me know if this solution works for you.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.2-SNAPSHOT'
    compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.2-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```